# NSMatrix has too many buttons?

Tags: cocoa, nsmatrix

I'm trying to make a radio button set with two options, "Single" and "Sweep". I dragged a radio button into my storyboard and then added it to a matrix using Editor->Embed in. I then changed the number of rows to two.

I see two radio buttons in the IB display, the Inspector says there's two rows, and when I run it I only see two buttons. However, there are three buttons in the hierarchy display:

[image]

It seems the second one named "Single" is real, when you click on the lines in the left pane you can see a shadowed selection appear in the same place as the first button. I tried everything I could to delete that entry, but nothing seems to work.

This may simply be a IB bug that I should report, but I'm not sure I simply didn't do something wrong in setting this up. Anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: If you don't need to support < 10.8, I'd skip using an NSMatrix (since its use is deprecated) and use 2 radio buttons with the same action: "The primary use of NSMatrix is for radio button groups, so recall that for applications linked on 10.8 or later, radio buttons that share the same parent view and action will operate as a group."

Comment: Oh! I managed to miss that over the years. Thanks Wevah, that makes my life a lot easier, because it also solves how to bind it properly - I just bound one to the NSNegateBoolean of the other. Works perfect!

Comment: @Wevah: just a note, I tried this in the next screen where I used radios. But since there's no action associated with a binding (often), this approach doesn't work. Embedding them in a Matrix makes it work, so I'll have to use that until they come up with a better solution.

Comment: Shouldn't the bindings take care of that, though? Do you still get the nice animations if you use a matrix?

Comment: You do if you use a matrix, but not if you don't. I guess I could also bind them to a dummy action method to trigger what you were talking about.

Comment: Probably nothing that'll stop a matrix from working if it works for you, though (hopefully).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first cell under the matrix in the document outline is the prototype cell. From the [NSMatrix Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMatrix/prototype):

> The prototype cell that’s copied whenever the matrix creates a new cell.

`NSMatrix` has a bunch of methods like `addRow` and `insertColumn:` that make copies of the prototype.

Comment: Ahhh, RTFMoreCarefully. It might be a good idea for that cell to be named "Prototype" so that's more obvious!

Comment: Indeed. I figured it out by looking at the XML (right click XIB > Open As > Source Code).